# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class ParallelArray {

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] charArray = new char[5];
        int[] intArray = new int[5];
        char ch;
        int count;
        System.out.println("Enter 5 characters: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            charArray[i] = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a character: ");
            ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
            int location = search(ch, charArray);
            intArray[location]++;
            System.out.println("Again? 1-yes, 0-no");
            count = sc.nextInt();
        } while (count == 1);

        printBothLists(charArray, intArray);
    }

    public static void printBothLists(char[] charArray, int[] intArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(charArray[i] + " - " + intArray[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int search(char ch, char[] charArray) {
        int count = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            if (ch == charArray[i]) {
                count = i;
                return count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

If I enter 5 characters, a,b,c,d,e for the array and later ask the user t enter another set of character and I enter a,b,c,d, y. It will exit out of the program and give error :`- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`.

Comment: `charArray[i]=sc.next().charAt(0);` concerns me.  Every call to `sc.next()` advances the scanner past whatever line of text you've entered.  Perhaps you need a better way of *split*ting up the `String`?  (hint, hint)

Answer (score 2):

You're not checking for the possibility that a user may enter a character that does not exist...

```
int location = search(ch, charArray);
intArray[location]++; // <-- The index is invalid...
```

You need to make a check before trying to access the array...

```
int location = search(ch, charArray);
if (location >= 0 && location < intArray.length) {
    intArray[location]++; // <-- The index is invalid...
} else {
    System.out.println("'" + ch + "' does not exist");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You are correct sir.....i missed out on that part.